# Object key is undefined in loop map react render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I can access the whole object like

```
<Card.Content>{_this.state.index}</Card.Content>
```

It says Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {name, title, email, phone, photo, officename, manageremail}).

But that's not my goal, I simply want to render one of the keys

```
 const componentsMobile = this.state.components.map(item => (
      <Card fluid key={index}>
        <Card.Content>
          <Card.Header>{item.value.label}</Card.Header>
        </Card.Content>
        <Card.Content extra>{_this.state.index.email}</Card.Content>
        {/* <Card.Content extra>{_this.state.index.value[item.source]}</Card.Content> */}
      </Card>
 ))
```

> index.cjs.js:798 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of
>   undefined

I am not sure why it's undefined

Comment: This error occurs due to the _this.state.index.email, could you please console the value once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the check as `_this.state && _this.state.index && _this.state.index.email`.

If the email is present, it will show the email otherwise, it will not show anything and this error will also not come.

You can put the solution directly where you are using `_this.state.index.email` as of now.

Comment: Works fine! Can you please elaborate on why _this.state.index do not raise an error in this example?

Comment: I do not have your whole code but seems like at the very early stage when the component renders, you do not have `index` variable in `state` which will make `_this.state.index` as undefined. So, when JSX tries to read a property of `undefined`, it will cause the issue which you were facing.